# KoHana Cache Error

Tags: caching, kohana

I am trying to debug a kohana project which is not working for some corrupted cache file

```
Cache_Exception [ 0 ]: Kohana_Cache_File::get corrupted cache file!
MODPATH/cache/classes/kohana/cache/file.php [ 152 ]
147                 $lifetime = $data->fgets();
148 
149                 // If we're at the EOF at this point, corrupted!
150                 if ($data->eof())
151                 {
152                     throw new Cache_Exception(__METHOD__.' corrupted cache file!');
153                 }
154 
155                 $cache = '';
156 
157                 while ($data->eof() === FALSE)
APPPATH/classes/helper/dropdown.php [ 10 ] » Kohana_Cache_File->get(arguments)
APPPATH/views/search/index.php [ 36 ] » Helper_DropDown::states(arguments)
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/view.php [ 61 ] » include(arguments)
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/view.php [ 343 ] » Kohana_View::capture(arguments)
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/view.php [ 228 ] » Kohana_View->render()
APPPATH/views/layouts/default.php [ 71 ] » Kohana_View->__toString()
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/view.php [ 61 ] » include(arguments)
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/view.php [ 343 ] » Kohana_View::capture(arguments)
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/controller/template.php [ 44 ] » Kohana_View->render()
APPPATH/classes/controller/common/base.php [ 35 ] » Kohana_Controller_Template->after()
{PHP internal call} » Controller_Common_Base->after()
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php [ 119 ] » ReflectionMethod->invoke(arguments)
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request/client.php [ 64 ] » Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(arguments)
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request.php [ 1154 ] » Kohana_Request_Client->execute(arguments)
DOCROOT/index.php [ 111 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()
```

This is the trace log. I am unable to understand how to make this work ?

Comment: Does the cache file exist? If so, does it contain any data?

Comment: Yes, It does exists and has ORM Query data cached in the file

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Does it happen every time the file is generated?

Comment: Consider creating this CLI command posted at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48513944/6226495