# What's the simplest way to clear the cache in Kohana 3.3.1?

Tags: php, caching, kohana-3.3

I inherited a web application in Kohana 3.3.1 (I'm used to working in Symfony).

What is the simplest command or process to clear the entire cache?

I've looked at

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/5779/how-i-can-clear-the-cache-folder-in-ko3/p1

and

http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~powerpak/kohanadocs/libraries/cache.html

But I'm really looking for something that can be automated as part of our deploy/CI process.

Thanks!

Comment: What Cache? I don't actually know this framework. Assuming some sort of key/value store abstraction in that framework? Maybe using APC?.. oh, file cache?

Comment: So, seems scripting the clearing of a known file directory should be easy enough. If needing to use your application's code to accomplish it then create a non public _preRelease.php or _postRelase.php script or something you can fire off a request to.

Comment: Thanks! I tried manually deleting the contents of the cache directory, but it didn't clear out the particular results I was expecting. Good point about just creating an extension to run myself, but I was hoping there was something built in, like Symfony's cache:clear command. The cache itself is a Kohana module, but pretty much tightly integrated with the core.

Comment: If you want to be able to fire off something like `php cache.php clear` from the command line that is pretty trivial. You can even use symphony console in a stand alone fashion if you like their approach. Same concept though of just having an 'action' on your application which you can invoke... CLI or via web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what easiest way will be write a minion task ( https://github.com/kohana/minion )

Put your task in classes/Task/ClearCache.php

```
<?php
class Task_ClearCache extends Minion_Task {

    protected function _execute(array $params)
    {
        Cache::instance()->delete_all();
    }
} 
?>
```

And run it into your BASEPATH directory 
`> php minion.php ClearCache`